# CakePHP is ignoring find conditions

Tags: cakephp

I try to retrieve all database records from Tournament which belongs to User.

```
$cond = array('condition' => array('Tournament.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')));
$data = $this->User->Tournament->find('all', $cond);
```

It finds all the tournaments, the script seems to not care about the condition.

`User` hasAndBelongsToMany `Tournament`. I made a function called "tournaments" in `UsersController` where the code part above is included.

I hope this is enough information, otherwise tell me what's needed and I will provide it later.

Comment: Why not just use a single line?  `$data=$this->User->Tournament->findAllByUserId($this->Auth->user('id'));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read the CakePHP documentation more carefully:

```
conditions (not condition)
```